# Issue with Presenting UIViewController as a modalview from a subview-controller of the rootView controller

Tags: ios, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have a parent view controller which is a rootViewController of the UIWindow. And this UIViewController has two sub views(viewcontrollers added). And when I tap a button in the right side subview-controller it should open a modal view. When I try to do this by using [self presentModalView:vc] from the right side view it collapses the whole UI. Hence I changed the code like, i.e I presented the modal view from the parentViewController through the AppDelegate. Because appdelegate has parentView's instance. When I do like this modal view appears without any problem.

My question, Is this the correct approach? Is there any clear procedure/documentation about presenting a modal view, do's and don't?.

And I am facing another problem is when I try to present another modal view over this first modalview it does not work.

Please clarify me.

**Edited:** added the code sample to simulate the issue. RootViewController is added to the window. RightViewController is the sub view of root view controller. When I click on the button on right view controller it will present the modal view controller as a modal view. Here is the problem. The modal view is not occur 
properly. I hope this helps you.

--
Thanks in advance. @durai

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class RightViewController;

@interface RootViewController : UIViewController {
    UIView *bgView;
    RightViewController *rightView;
}

@end

#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "RightViewController.h"

@implementation RootViewController
/*
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
*/

- (void) loadView
{
    bgView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame];

    rightView = [[RightViewController alloc] init];
    [bgView addSubview:rightView.view];

    self.view = bgView;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

/*
// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView
{
}
*/

/*
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
*/

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}

@end

//  RightViewController.h
//  ModalViewTester
//
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ModalViewController.h"

@interface RightViewController : UIViewController <ModalViewDelegate>{
    UIView *rightView;
    UIButton *button;
}

- (void) showModalView;

@end




#import "RightViewController.h"

@implementation RightViewController
/*
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
*/
- (void) loadView
{
    rightView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320, 40, 250, 250)];
    rightView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    self.view = rightView;

    button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 30);
    [button setTitle:@"Modal" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(showModalView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [rightView addSubview:button];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 50, 100, 50)];
    label.text = @"Right View";
    label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14.0f];
    [rightView addSubview:label];

    self.view = rightView;
}

- (void) showModalView
{
    ModalViewController *mc = [[ModalViewController alloc] init];
    self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
    self.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
    [self presentModalViewController:mc animated:YES];
    [mc release];
}

- (void) closeView:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

/*
// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView
{
}
*/

/*
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
*/

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}

@end

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol ModalViewDelegate

-(void) closeView:(NSDictionary *) dict;

@end

@interface ModalViewController : UIViewController {
    UIView *modalView;
    UIButton *cancelButton;
    id <ModalViewDelegate> delegate;
}

- (void) closeView:(id) sender;

@end

#import "ModalViewController.h"


@implementation ModalViewController

/*
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
*/

- (void) loadView
{
    NSLog(@"Inside ModalViewController - loadView method");
    modalView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame];
    modalView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    cancelButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 50, 70, 40)];
    [cancelButton setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cancelButton addTarget:self action:@selector(closeView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [modalView addSubview:cancelButton];

    self.view = modalView;
}

- (void) closeView:(id) sender
{
    [delegate closeView:nil];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

/*
// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView
{
}
*/

/*
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
*/

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: Without seeing your code I have to guess what you are doing. Therefore I cannot help you.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to really grasp your problem without any code, but if it's documentation your looking for I think this is what you need to look at:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html